# Illustrator batch save files to 1024x1024 png maintaining proportions

Tags: batch, adobe-illustrator

I got a bunch of ai files, that I need to save to png.

Is it possible to save them with an Image output of ex. 1024 x 1024 while still maintain the proportions?

The perfect solution would be if you could specify an margin. Lets say the output image should be 1024 x 1024 pixels, but with a margin of 24 pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Illustrator content doesn't have edges as such.

You could put a square box surrounding the content with the margin you would like to see, and then when you export to png, you can specify the dimensions of the output to be 1024x1024.  The square box artificially puts a boundary on the content.

Or the correct way to do this would be to add crop marks where you want the edges of your image to be.  Filter -> Create -> Crop Marks

Line these up with where you would want the edges to be if you were to print the image and guillotine it.  These marks are also respected when you export to an image format.